# 404 GET /app - Angular2 quickstart

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to migrate my app based on the old angular2 quickstart to the new one (which has new folder hierarchy).

When hitting `npm start` I'm getting `404 GET /app` error.
It's important to mention that my `app.module.ts` file is placed under `/app/modules/app/app.module.ts`

I tried to change paths with no luck but I still suspect that it's something that is related to my configurations.

**main.ts:**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/modules/app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**systemjs.config.js:**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>    
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myApp",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.6",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.1",
    "systemjs": "0.20.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",    
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"    
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `systemjs.config.js`

In the `package` entry change the `app` to `app: {main: 'app/modules/app/app.module', defaultExtension: 'js'}`

If you have a bundle of your app created somewhere you should point the `app` key to that bundle instead of `app.module`.

Comment: actually just: 
app: {main: 'modules/app/app.module', defaultExtension: 'js'}